# I need to print multiple copies of a barcode label in VB.NET with crystal report

Tags: vb.net

i have tried

```
Private Sub MOSTRAR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MOSTRARButton.Click
```

BARCODEReportViewer.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\BARCODE\BarcodeReport.rpt"
Dim box As Integer = TextBox2.Text
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim stringFormula As String
stringFormula = "{PRODUCT.PRO_UNIT_BARCODE} = '" & TextBox1.Text.ToString() & "'"
stringFormula &= "Or {PRODUCT.PRO_BARCODE_PACK} = '" & TextBox1.Text.ToString() & "'"
While index <= box
BARCODEReportViewer.SelectionFormula = stringFormula
index += 1
End While

`BARCODEReportViewer.Refresh()
        BARCODEReportViewer.RefreshReport()
    End Sub`

Comment: Could you be more precise? Where did your code go wrong?

Comment: when i run the page it does loop, but does not repeat the barcode, if I type 3, it loops 3 times, but does not display 3 barcodes. i notice that in c# it works using parse, but i cant get it to work in vb.net